# Pandas Dataframe - enforce data properties

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandera

I would like to enforce properties on pandas data tables.
Mostly a "uniqueness" of "primary keys" in the table would be interesting.

Is there a way to ensure such properties without having to call a validation function?
It would be preferable that pandas throws an error if ANY modification to the table breaches the defined rules.

I already found a the package pandera which only works when a validation function is called. The checks are not enforced on the table at any time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `set_index()` function to set a column or set of columns as the index of a DataFrame.

you should note that if the column is not unique (has duplicates) then Pandas will raise a `KeyError`.

The question has no actual code to debug, so i post a boiler plate example of what i might look like:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = df.set_index("id")
```

There are different variants on this.

Comment: Thank you but this not what I am searching for.
It is still possible to create duplicate index entries.
e.g. concatenating the same df twice:

pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2], "b":[2,3], "id":["a","b"]}).set_index(["id","a"]);
pd.concat([df, df])